# adding a room on an existing bottom floor

Tags: structural

Can the top-plates be the regular double 2 by 4s when a room-addition is going up or does it have to be a heavy beam in all cases? I have not tried anything yet want to know first before attempting anything. My question is about adding a top floor to an existing frame structure, not a basement. Is a double top plate with 2x4s sufficient to hold up a new floor on existing frame walls or should the 2x4 top plates be replaced with a solid beam like a 4x6 etc. The structure is not in the USA but I am sure that the sense of doing it right is still important. Thank you, Frank

Comment: Are you asking about adding a non-load bearing wall in to an existing structure?

Comment: If this is not in the USA, where is it? This can help us understand the typical construction in the area.

Comment: You said you're "adding a top floor to an existing frame structure...to hold up a new floor on existing frame walls." Are you wanting to add a second story to an existing single-story building? If so, simply adding a 2x4 on top of an existing wall won't be enough to support the weight of walls, floors, furniture, and people of another story. Please tell us more about your goals.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about dividing an existing basement into rooms; a double 2x4 top plate is fine. If you have any metal poles, etc. supporting the floor(s) above, you will have to leave them in place. In this case, you might consider using 2x6 materials instead of 2x4. In this manner the poles, etc. could be incorporated into the new walls.